# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qwt_text_label'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Should be an easy fix but apparently isn't. I'm trying to run PyQt5 on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I have installed (or at least I think I have) Qt and PyQt5. I was even able to successfully execute `pyuic5 main_window.ui -o MainWindow.py` without any issues.

But when I run my code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MainWindow.py", line 79, in <module>
    from qwt_text_label import QwtTextLabel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qwt_text_label'
```

What package am I missing? how do I install it? is it a linking error, or path variable? Any help would be appreciated.

---

Installation commands I have run:

```
python3.8 -m pip install pyqt5
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

---

Here is my main_window.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>970</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>310</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>401</width>
      <height>311</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>350</y>
      <width>951</width>
      <height>171</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <widget class="QwtTextLabel" name="recordTimer">
         <property name="plainText">
          <string>00:00</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="recordButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Record</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="stopButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Stop</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="Line" name="line">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QwtTextLabel" name="TextLabel">
         <property name="plainText">
          <string>General Instructions</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QwtTextLabel" name="TextLabel_2">
         <property name="plainText">
          <string>Sentence to be read</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>970</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QwtTextLabel</class>
   <extends>QFrame</extends>
   <header>qwt_text_label.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

and here is the MainWindow.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main_window.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(970, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 20, 401, 311))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 951, 171))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.recordTimer = QwtTextLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.recordTimer.setObjectName("recordTimer")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.recordTimer)
        self.recordButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.recordButton.setObjectName("recordButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.recordButton)
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.stopButton.setObjectName("stopButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.TextLabel = QwtTextLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.TextLabel.setObjectName("TextLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.TextLabel)
        self.TextLabel_2 = QwtTextLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.TextLabel_2.setObjectName("TextLabel_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.TextLabel_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 970, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.recordTimer.setPlainText(_translate("MainWindow", "00:00"))
        self.recordButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Record"))
        self.stopButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        self.TextLabel.setPlainText(_translate("MainWindow", "General Instructions"))
        self.TextLabel_2.setPlainText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sentence to be read"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
from qwt_text_label import QwtTextLabel
```

Comment: show your main_window.ui

Comment: That is a Qwt widget, which is not a standard Qt widget and as such requires the relative python binding, maybe https://pypi.org/project/PythonQwt/ ?

Comment: Installing PythonQwt has not resolved the problem. Thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing this?

```
from qwt.text import QwtTextLabel
```

requires python QWT.

Comment: It resolves the issue for the time being. But I can't call the loadUi as follows, because loadUi relies on the problematic code:

from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

Comment: Does this work? "from PyQt5 import uic", in that case you can invoke uic.loadUi